# What's a good hub for ultra bikepacking races?

Tags: wheels, hub, zipp

I've now twice had the body of the rear hub destroyed during bikepacking racing (999 Miglia 2017 and Race Around Denmark 2018).

I'm currently using Zipp 303 Disc with 177D hubs from 2016 and it seems they can't take the load. I'm "only" 66 kg, but the bike is heavy during these races.

Should I rebuild the rear wheel with a sturdier hub or change wheels when participating in ultra-distance unsupported (hence the heavy bags) races?

Zipp user manual: https://www.zipp.com/_media/pdfs/manuals/2016_ZIPPSPCRevA.pdf

Comment: Sounds like you have the wrong parts - a 303 is a racing wheel, not  really suitable for a heavy load on bumpy roads.

Comment: Agreed. Racing parts are built for speed, not durability. Get something made for touring -- with all the stuff you're carrying, the weight difference will matter less.

Comment: All participants had racing wheels at Race Across Denmark,and I wasn't the only one on Zipps. According to Zipp, they're good for 113 kg (250 lbs), so I'm well within the limit. But you're saying that they can't be trusted? Make no mistake, during a race like 999 Miglia or Alpi 4000, both with 20.000 hm, weight is of significant importance.